# Pixma M310 Cables

Tags: power-supply, canon-pixma, cable

Hallo everyone,

i have a pixma m310 copier/scanner/printer from a friend that does not work anymore. The thing is before i can start trying to fix it, i need the cables, because he neglected to include them in the package.

I would need a connection from Computer to printer and a networkcable (i could do without it even, because there are power cords for different countries included and i could use an adapter. ) But even a thorough google search did not point me to a place where i could aquire the connection printer->computer. So my question is:

where can i get those cables from?

cheers